# Ubuntu doesn't start after I installed updates

Tags: upgrade, updates, system-installation

When I install Ubuntu, I set it so. Then asks to restart, I restart the pc, it comes standard in Ubuntu.

After I install updates it asks to restart again, I restart the pc again, more so that he did not re-enter the Ubuntu, it gets a black screen... Why?

Comment: We understand that, but your question is no more important than any other, please wait for someone to answer it. If you need more urgent help you can try [the IRC help channel](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat).

Comment: +1 Here, samething  with the propietary drivers, it doesn't even allow me to login on shell.

Comment: Please read. http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask